# Check pandas dataframe with ge(2)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to check the columns of a pandas dataframe with 0 and 1 with the following code, if there are any values greater or equal to 2:

```
df_plus1 = df_plus1.iloc[:,2:].fillna(0)
if df_plus1.ge(2) == True:
```

It returns me an Error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

How can I check the df and do not get an error?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this dataframe:

```py
   Col1  Col2
0     1     2
1     3     4
```

You can use `.any()` to get if there's value greater than 2 in the dataframe:

```py
print(df.ge(2).any())
```

Prints:

```
Col1    True
Col2    True
dtype: bool
```

So `Col1` has value `>2` and `Col2` too.

To get single `True`/`False` value, use `.any()` again:

```
print(df.ge(2).any().any())
```

Prints:

```
True
```

---

So the answer to your question is:

```
if df.ge(2).any().any() == True:
    print("OK")
```